# Get list of people who liked a status through FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I can get the number of likes on a status through this FQL query -

```sql
SELECT like_info,
       message,
       status_id,
       time,
       uid
FROM   status
WHERE uid = me()
```

I'd like to get the separate user ID's of the likes (if not possible for friends of the authenticated user, just the user himself/herself). It's possible through the Graph API through a command like this -

```
me/?fields=statuses
```

Is the same thing possible through FQL?

Answer (score 2):

You can select IDs from [status table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/status/) for user and then use them to select data from [like table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like)

```sql
SELECT user_id,
       object_id
FROM   like 
WHERE  object_id IN(
           SELECT status_id
           FROM   status
           WHERE uid = me() )
```

You may group result by `object_id` on your side.